# The only solution of the equation ${72_8!}/{18_2!}=4^x$ is $x=9$

Tags: functions, proof-verification, factorial

### Problem and Definitions

If $n_a!:=n(n-a)(n-2a)(n-3a)\ldots(n-ka):n>ka$, how should I go about solving this?: $$\dfrac{72_8!}{18_2!}=4^x$$

### Attempt

$$\dfrac{72(72-8)(72-16)(72-24)(72-32)(72-40)(72-48)(72-56)(72-64)}{18(18-2)(18-4)(18-6)(18-8)(18-10)(18-12)(18-14)(18-16)}=4^x$$
which is then simplified into (execution)
$$\dfrac{72(64)(56)(48)(40)(32)(24)(16)(8)}{18(16)(14)(12)(10)(8)(6)(4)(2)}=4^x$$
Now we see there is a bijective function from the multiplicands; $72=18\times 4$, $56=14\times 4$, $64=16\times 4$, $56=14\times 4$, $48=14\times 4$... So we can simplify to, by dividing each top be the bottom:
$$\dfrac{4(4)(4)(4)(4)(4)(4)(4)(4)}{1}=4^x$$
to
$$4^24^24^24^24^1=4^x$$
to
$$4^{2+2+2+2+1}=4^x$$
then to
$$4^{9}=4^x.$$
From this, we can obviously see that $x=9$.

### Question

Am I correct in assuming that there is a bijective function between every dividend and divisor? And, am I also correct in taking each dividend and dividing it by its respective divisor? Generally, is this 'proof' correct?

Comment: Yes, your reasoning is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is fine.  You don't need a bijective function.  What you are doing is dividing the numerator and denominator by the same amount a bunch of times.  As you say, this is made easier because you can divide each factor in order by the other, resulting in a quotient of $4$, then just count up the factors of $4$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
if $a|n$,
as it does in your case,
then,
if $b = \frac{n}{a}$,

$\begin{array}\\
n_a!
&=\prod\limits_{k=0}^{b-1} (n-ka)\\
&=\prod\limits_{k=0}^{b-1} (ba-ka)\\
&=a^b\prod\limits_{k=0}^{b-1} (b-k)\\
&=a^b\prod\limits_{k=1}^{b} k\\
&=a^b b!\\
&=a^{n/a} (n/a)!
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$\dfrac{72_8!}{18_2!}
=\dfrac{8^9 9!}{2^9 9!}
=\dfrac{8^9}{2^9}
= 4^9
$.

Answer (score 0):

Short solution (Ross answer as a formula)
$$
\dfrac{9\cdot 8 - 8k}{9\cdot 2 - 2k}=\dfrac{8\cdot(9-k)}{2\cdot( 9 - k)}=4 \qquad (0\leq k\leq 8)
$$